# How to render Font/Text in wayland in Ubuntu with egl?

Tags: ubuntu, freetype, wayland, weston

So how can we render text in ubuntu without the modern gtk , qt libraries ?
I am trying wayland and have done with the sample code could able to populate designs with color buffers using egl and gl

So is there a way we can render fonts on the egl surface buffers ??

well i wanted to try freetype-gl , but there ae no video guides for installing it in ubuntu instead they are on windows !

Actually i am trying to create a combo box without the use of GTK library , i have done with the display stuff like when click i can populate option blocks , but cannot able to render text in those blocks ? neither there are many sample code or documentations in the internet to help me ??

I am expecting a simple and straight answer , can we render text without any libraries in wayland ??